# How do I rename a column based on a variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rename

I want to rename a column at the end of a series of queries based on a variable.  It would perform something like this:

```
 DECLARE @formTable TABLE (FormID varchar(max))
    INSERT @formTable SELECT 'Form1'AS FormID;
    INSERT @formTable SELECT 'Form2'AS FormID;
    INSERT @formTable SELECT 'Form3' AS FormID;
    INSERT @formTable SELECT 'Form5'     AS FormID;


 DECLARE @CCount TABLE (FormID varchar(max), Present varchar(max))
    INSERT @CCount SELECT 'Form1' AS FormID, 'Yes' AS Present;
    INSERT @CCount SELECT 'Form2' AS FormID, 'Yes' AS Present;

 DECLARE @subject varchar(12);
 SET @subject = 'Subject 22'

 SELECT t.FormID AS Form, Present  
 FROM  @formTable t LEFT JOIN @CCount c ON t.FormID = c.FormID
```

which creates a table that looks like this:

```
 Form     Present
 Form1      Yes
 Form2      Yes
 Form3      NULL
 Form5      NULL
```

I want it to look like this :

```
  Form     Subject 22
  Form1      Yes
  Form2      Yes
  Form3      NULL
  Form5      NULL
```

How can I accomplish this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use variables for column names - you can do this using [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html), though you need to be very careful with dynamic SQL and not introduce a [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: If I put the variable in a table would that help ?

Comment: @user918967 - No. You must specify the alias of a column, unless dynamic SQL is used.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'SELECT t.FormID AS Form, Present as [' + @subject + 
    '] FROM  @formTable t LEFT JOIN @CCount c ON t.FormID = c.FormID'
exec @sql
```